# Error using Hibernate with H2 in memory database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm working with Hibernate. How can I configure my persistence.xml to have an H2 in-memory database?

My **persistence.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>com.mastertheboss.domain.Employee</class>
        <class>com.mastertheboss.domain.Department</class>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But when I run my app I get the following **error**:

`Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EMPLOYEE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEE [42102-171]
Error Code: 42102
Call: SELECT ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEE
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employee sql="SELECT ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEE")`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to "create" the first time you run your application, to create the tables

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

and then (if you don't want the tables to be recreated and emptied every time you start) set it to "validate".

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

To create the schema automatically, add if-not-exists to your connection url like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/<filename>;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS <schema_name>" />
```

Comment: @andPat this soulution is probably the most correct. If you can't get this to work, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: but if I do so I have to delete ` <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should replace that one.

Comment: Do not forget to fill in your <filename> and <schema_name>.

Comment: Do you have any clue as to why `create` will add the constraints, but `update` will not? Even when I start with an empty (nonexisting even), or in-memory database?

Comment: @Barry NL If the database is in memory (which I assume it means it runs as long as the app itself), why would be the case for validate?

Comment: @Whimusical you are right, in case of an in-memory database (which is the case here) the validate does not make any sense.