# Hibernate SchemaExport fails to first create schema

Tags: hibernate, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss-arquillian, hbm2ddl

I am running tests using Arquillian, JBoss, JPA/Hibernate, H2 DB and Maven. In my test persistence.xml file I have:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```

For now I have a single User class mapped to a 'users' table via Hibernate annotations.

Things are almost working. The problem is Hibernate is trying to execute:

```
drop table my_schema.users if exists
```

But the schema, 'my_schema' doesn't exist so it fails (I'm running against an in-memory DB after all).

How do I get hibernate to execute the 'create schema my_schema' step that it seems to be forgetting?

**Update:**
The messages I see from Hibernate:

```
09:42:45,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'test.war#ccmc'
09:42:45,524 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
09:42:45,532 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
09:42:45,535 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
09:42:45,542 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
09:42:45,572 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ccmc
    ...]
09:42:45,739 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
09:42:45,956 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
09:42:45,962 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
09:42:45,965 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
09:42:45,973 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
09:42:45,976 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
09:42:46,003 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
09:42:46,269 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
09:42:46,275 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate: drop table ccmc.users if exists
09:42:46,283 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table ccmc.users if exists
09:42:46,283 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) Schema "CCMC" not found; SQL statement:
drop table ccmc.users if exists [90079-161]
09:42:46,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate: create table ccmc.users (user_id decimal(19,2) generated by default as identity, email varchar(100) not null unique, primary key (user_id))
09:42:46,285 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table ccmc.users (user_id decimal(19,2) generated by default as identity, email varchar(100) not null unique, primary key (user_id))
09:42:46,285 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) Schema "CCMC" not found; SQL statement:
create table ccmc.users (user_id decimal(19,2) generated by default as identity, email varchar(100) not null unique, primary key (user_id)) [90079-161]
09:42:46,286 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: could you post the error stacktraces?

Comment: sure...there aren't actually any stacktraces per se, but I posted the server output. of course later when I try to do something, like save a new user there are stacktraces because the 'users' table doesn't exist, but that's expected...

Comment: What if you change "create-drop" as "create"?

Comment: Yeah I tried that just for the heck of it, but it doesn't work. If 'create-drop' doesn't work, then 'create' won't work either because the only difference between the 2 is that 'create-drop' drops everything at the end of the tests, 'create' does not. But my problem is at the start of the tests, not the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer in another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417425/error-using-hibernate-with-h2-in-memory-database).

When defining the connection URL to the DB, this needs to be added: "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ". So the full URL in the persistence.xml file looks like:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ccmc</connection-url>
```

where `ccmc` is the name of the schema to be created. Param `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` is unrelated with the problem and can be safely omited regarding this matter.

Comment: If you want to run multiple scripts, you can do this:
`jdbc:h2:mem:test-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ccmc\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ccmc2`